# Paste foreign characters to a new file

Tags: bash, paste

I was trying to use the `paste` command (in bash for MacOS) to write a number of files to a new (tab separated) file. The problem looks like:

```
paste file_1 file_2 file_3 > new_file
```

Each of the files file_n contain numbers or characters stored in one column. E.g.:

```
STND
KSMN
PQhr
yeIE
```

But then some of the files/columns contain foreign characters, e.g.:

```
ÚÐÆØ
Ý?íS
??ðý
Ó123
```

The above mentioned `paste` command can create the new_file as long as there are no foreign characters, but is unable to do so for the files/columns containing foreign characters.

Does anyone know if/how `paste` can handle this, or if there is an alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: What does this command output? `env | grep -Ei "lang|locale"`

Comment: Can I ask you how to use this command to the problem? Sorry, I'm not a very experienced scripting person.

Comment: You just copy it by selecting it with the mouse and pressing `cmd+c` and then you start a Terminal and paste it into the Terminal by pressing `cmd+v` and hit `Enter/Return`. Start a Terminal by pressing `cmd+spacebar` and typing `Term` and hitting `Enter/Return`.

Comment: OK that's done, but nothing happens. It just goes to a new command line. I also tried to initiate the script with this command (after the #!/bin/bash), if that's what you mean, but it still reports the error:

paste: Error reading file_2

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

@Mark, you are right the paste command does work if changes are made in the LC_CTYPE variable. My locale variables originally read:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

But LC_CTYPE="UTF-8" causes the script to fail on paste. However, if changed to "C" the script runs perfectly well:

```
$ locale
LANG=  
LC_COLLATE="C"  
LC_CTYPE="C"  
LC_MESSAGES="C"  
LC_MONETARY="C"  
LC_NUMERIC="C"  
LC_TIME="C"  
LC_ALL=
```

Upon this change,

$ paste file_1 file_2 file_3 > new_file

works perfectly well, even with foreign characters.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this has to do with your locale - where your computer thinks you are and how you want it to interpret characters, money, numbers and times.

You can check your locale by typing:

```
locale
```

in your Terminal - mine looks like this:

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I am guessing that you need to set either `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` to something with `utf8` in it before you run `paste` something like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 paste file1 file2
```

or maybe

```
LANG=C paste file1 file2
```

Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you've spent on trying to help me out!
I'm working with OS X Yosemite and you may be working with proper Linux (?) The `locate` command is probably different between these systems. This is what I get:

`$ locate
usage: locate [-0Scims] [-l limit] [-d database] pattern ...

default database: `/var/db/locate.database' or $LOCATE_PATH`

My foreign characters are in codepage 850, dos format. Don't know if that makes the problem easier to solve?

Comment: It is `locaLe` rather than `locaTe` ;-)

Comment: That was different! Sorry for my silliness :) I'll try to proceed from here and see if I can solve it; thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just to let you know that I solved the problem with `awk`. It doesn't complain about the foreign characters nor alters them from the original. The script reads:
`pr -m -t -s\  file_1 file_2 | awk '{print $1,$2}' > new_file`
No doubt that `awk` is aw(k)esome :-)